# Is it better to trade one at a time? or is 'all' just as good?

Tags: kittens-game

When farming blueprints, it's often easier to trade rather than go through the production chain of furs to blueprints (about 21k furs to a blueprint at 4 output/craft).

There is the option of sending either 25, 100, or all of your trade runs at once (the 25 and 100 was part of 9.8.2).  Is there any difference in the rate of blueprint farming between lots of clicks or the speed trading?

Comment: I see you got sucked in.

Comment: @AshleyNunn of course... though I wouldn't miss asking a good question if one comes to mind.

Comment: @AshleyNunn it's the new Farmville :P

Comment: @BillyMailman exactly.

Comment: As an aside: You should be both trading *and* crafting. Idle with Mints running to get furs without using up catpower on hunting that'd be better served trading (you're not trading while idle). Later on, Printing Press, Offset Press, and CAD System will help immensely with the crafting route. Plus, if you stockpile compendiums, they boost max science.

Comment: @BillyMailman indeed I am, and its crunching away.  I'm currently at the 50/60 blueprint technologies.  Its just that in the time it takes to create a set of blueprints I can hit trade all and run dozen caravans and maybe pickup a blueprint or two which can cut down the real time spent on getting that next technology or workshop upgrade or additional building.

Comment: Yeah, it's a heck of a grind in the early phases of blueprint tech. Once you get those upgrades, though, it changes a lot. Especially since every workshop/factory boost is improving every stage of the construction. Either way, good luck with it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the game code, the tradeAll function, in diplomacy.js, delegates the work off to tradeMultiple. That function takes in an amount, subtracts the costs, then does the following:

```
    for (var i = 0; i<amt; i++){
        var yieldRes = this.tradeInternal(true);    //supress msg
        for (var res in yieldRes) {
            yieldResTotal[res] = yieldResTotal[res] ? yieldResTotal[res] + yieldRes[res] : yieldRes[res];
        }
    }
    this.printYieldOutput(yieldResTotal);
```

Thus, all that happens when you hit Trade All, is that the exact same code runs over and over, the results are summed up, and a single line is printed in the log. The results are therefore guaranteed to be no different than if you had hit the Trade button over and over.

Incidentally, the same sort of design is used for things like crafting, hunting, etc. to make sure the calculations always line up the same, no matter what sized batches you craft in.

Comment: Note that Trade All can exceed your resource caps - it may be better to use a series of single trades, just so you can pause to use up the resources when they hit the cap.